# Strange Arithmetic Error On String In Bash

Tags: bash

I'm making a very simple bash launcher script:

**Code:**

```
#!/bin/bash
function run {
    echo "Please enter the location of the folder that the file is in 
    (Exclude simplecalc1.x.x.py):"
    read folder
    cd "$folder"
    python3 "simplecalc1.0.14.py"
}
function notrun {
    read calcfilenr
    chmod +x "$calcfilenr"
    python3 "$calcfilenr"
}
echo "----(Linux Simplecalc launcher V1.0.14)----"
echo "Also, please run this script as sudo for it to run correctly."
echo "Please install python 3.x for simplecalc to run."
echo "Please type 'Y' if the folder is in a different location than"
echo "this script. ('N' if not.)"
read freq
if [[ $freq == "Y" ]];
then
    run
else
    notrun
fi
```

**Errors (Confused about 2nd one):**

```
chmod: cannot access 'simplecalc1.0.14.py': No such file or directory
./linuxlauncher.sh: line 16: simplecalc1.0.14.py: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0.14.py")
```

The second error is what is confusing me, Line 16 is a string though so why is it returning an error about invalid arithmetic operators?

I started programming on bash today, so I am a complete beginner as I only have 1 day of experience.

Full Input/Output:

```
~/Downloads 
➜ sudo ./linuxlauncher.sh
----(Linux Simplecalc launcher V1.0.14)----
Also, please run this script as sudo for it to run correctly.
Please install python 3.x for simplecalc to run.
Please type 'Y' if the folder is in a different location than
this script. (N, if script is in same folder)
Y
Please enter the full location of the folder that the file is in:
Please exclude 'simplecalc1.x.x from the folder location.
/home/yusef/Documents/SimpleLauncher/
Enter the name of the simplecalc file:
simplecalc1.0.14.py
chmod: cannot access 'simplecalc1.0.14.py': No such file or directory
./linuxlauncher.sh: line 16: simplecalc1.0.14.py: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0.14.py")
```

Comment: *"Also, please run this script as sudo for it to run correctly."* -- there isn't any reason to run this script using `sudo`. The purpose of `sudo` is to allow the non-admin users to do admin tasks like starting/stopping services, installing/updating software, changing the system configuration etc. Your script does not do any of these. If a command executed using `sudo` creates a file, modifying or removing it requires using `sudo` again. It's a never-ending whirlpool. **Do not** use `sudo` unless you are doing admin tasks!

Comment: Ahh, I see. I thought chmod required sudo, my fault.

Comment: How do i fix this? Is it an issue with Visual studio code?

Comment: It looks like you've been editing your script and are showing output from a different version of it. The wording of the questions is slightly different, and the script doesn't have the "Enter the name of the simplecalc file:" question at all.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I will use a different editor and see if the problem persists. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any shell arithmetic expression in the script you posted either. Also, you did not point out which line is line **16**. Do you expect us to count the lines for you? For debugging, you could run the script with `-x` turned on, to see exactly which statement causes the error.

Comment: That's because VS code was using an older version of the file, even though I restarted. Anyway I fixed it by reinstalling vscode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code can be simplified and I've succeeded with this rewrite in launching python3 scripts.

I had errors using your code, and although I cannot explain exactly what was going wrong, I do know how to get the function you want to work.

To avoid any errors in python3 trying to run the script, I like to create a variable that is the absolute path for the script; rather than using `cd` and `python3 [scriptName]`.

Like this:
`script_path="$folder/$script_name"`

In context:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! python3 --version; then
    printf 'Python3 is required\n' && exit
else echo; fi

run_script(){
    printf 'Enter the absolute path to the folder with the script you want to launch: (./ for current folder)\n'
    read folder

    cd $folder
    printf '\nType or copy in the name of the script that you want to run from this folder:\n\n'
    ls && echo

    read script_name
    script_path="$folder/$script_name"

    python3 $script_path
}

run_script
```

You'll notice I nonetheless left in `cd`, but this is just so the `ls` command can show your users the available scripts in the directory they've chosen. That line can be removed if you like, but in which case make sure to also remove the `ls` command as well since it would confuse your users.

Another thing I did was use an `if ! ...` (if NOT) conditional to check if the user has python3 installed. if not, they are warned and then the script exits.

Also instead of asking the user to enter Y or N to tell the script if the user wants to use the working directory, one can simply inform the user that they can enter `./` to select the current working directory; as I did in my solution code.

Please let me know if you still get any errors. The error message about the arithmetic operator seems to be coming from within the actual python script you are launching rather than your bash code.

Important Note:

The use of `function` is deprecated and eventually may cause errors in your script as any future bash features will not consider compatibility with that old syntax.